# Can I use abstract class (that implements interface) in designing a high level class diagram

Tags: java, design-patterns, design-principles

Can I use abstract class (that implements interface) in designing a class diagram? My lead points what if someone uses interface directly? And he suggests design should stick to interface and classes? Any reason behind that?

Comment: Any feedback on the answer you got? If you found it helpful, consider accepting it at some point. If not, let me know what is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do that.

A prominent example would be [AbstractList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html).

This abstract class provides a "basic" implementation of the list interface. So that more specific implementations, such as LinkedList and ArrayList can be written without duplicating a ton of common code.

Please note: in the above case the "core" behavior of that abstract class is to be a "List" implementation later on. But it is also very well possible to have abstract classes that implement certain interfaces "additionally", simply because it makes sense to do so.

You didn't ask about that specifically, but it is worth mentioning that Java8 introduced default methods to interfaces, and Java9 added private and static methods within interfaces.

This means: the example I gave could *nowadays* be written without the need for an abstract base class. That abstract base class does not have any *fields* (aka: no internal state). It does all its work by calling other methods of the List interface.

Thus: using default methods, you can create complex interfaces that *implement* behavior. By allowing for static/private methods, you can even address aspects of "clean code" (such as extracting common code into private helper methods to avoid duplication). But as mentioned: that only works for situations where you don't need fields to store internal state.

But coming back to your initial question: the answer is simply yes. And please understand that abstract classes became irrelevant just because of default methods. There might be other good reasons to use an abstract base class, instead of solely relying on "enhanced interfaces".

Comment: Cool Tks. I got this case. Can I specify State instead of behavior in abstract class? Ex: I want my concrete class to use "specific provider" for my child. Do you have any examples?

Comment: You are welcome. As said: please consider accepting at some point, or let me know if something is missing.